# SSIS - Merging rows with aggregate determinations

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm attempting to determine the best way, either in SSIS or straight TSQL, to merge two rows based on a given key, but taking specific data from each row based on various aggregate rules (MAX and SUM specifically). As an example, given the following dataset:

```
Customer    Name    Total   Date        Outstanding
12345       A       100     7/15/2015   500
12345               200     1/1/2015    300
456         B       500     1/2/2010    100
456         B       250     2/1/2015    900
78          C       100     9/15/2015   500
```

I wish to consolidate those to a single row per customer key, with the following rules as an example:

- If any name is null, use a corresponding value for that customer that is not null
- MAX(Total)
- MAX(Date)
- SUM(Outstanding)

The result set would be:

```
Customer    Name    Total   Date        Outstanding
12345       A       200     7/15/2015   800
456         B       500     2/1/2015    1000
78          C       100     9/15/2015   500
```

What's the best approach here? My first instinct is to query the table to join to itself on customer to get all values on a single row, and then use formulas in a Derived Column task in SSIS to determine the values to use. My concern there is that is not scalable - it works fine if I have a customer occur only twice in the main dataset, but the goal would be for the logic to work for N number of rows without needing to do a ton of rework. I'm sure there's also a TSQL approach that I'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If name column in your query is not empty then you can do that simply by using aggregate function in one query

```
    DECLARE @Customer TABLE
(
Customer INT,   Name varchar(10),   Total INT   , PurchaseDate DATE  ,      Outstanding  INT
)
INSERT INTO @Customer
SELECT 12345,'A',100,'7/15/2015',500 UNION
SELECT 12345,'A',200,'1/1/2015',300 UNION
SELECT 456,'B',500,'1/2/2010',100 UNION
SELECT 456,'B',250,'2/1/2015',900 UNION
SELECT 78,'C',100,'9/15/2015',500


SELECT Customer,NAME ,MAX(Total), MAX(PurchaseDate), SUM(outstanding)
FROM @Customer 
GROUP BY Customer, NAME
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84d54/7)

Now, if your name column is empty in few cases like you have mentioned in your example then you can update name table with correct name value